# mongodb find largest key inside an item in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection that has the following schema

```
{
  _id: ,
  data: {
       1: {
          values: ...
       },
       3: {
           values: ...
       }
       2: {
          values: ...
       }
   }
}
```

and I wanted to know if it would be possible to sort the items inside the data object or pick the highest values using core mongodb instead of retrieving them and sorting using javascript.

Comment: Why is data not an array like it seems it should be?

Comment: its actually a timevalue based data, the keys are the minutes. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Comment: Should be possible with [$objectToArray](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794) in v3.6. Until then map-reduce is the only option.

Comment: Whilst "possible" it's really kind of dumb. Even with `$objectToArray` to still need to `$unwind` and `$sort` and then `$group` again. All that just to "sort keys". Bottom line is that when using named keys for time series collection, then then last thing on your mind should be "sorting the results". If it is somehow "on your mind" then you simply have the **wrong data structure**. You only need named keys like this when you understand what that means. And if you are asking to "sort them", then it sounds like you don't understand the intent. Use an array if you want to sort.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it will be out soon

Comment: Dude it's out. [MongoDB 3.4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#apr-21-2017). Though it's not actually written into the documentation until 3.6. But the operator is already released. It's still not **the magic answer though**. Like I said. "You're doing it wrong" if you think you need the server to "sort" anything.

Comment: @NeilLunn that's great news.

Comment: @AlexBlex Considering that there have been answers posted on this site using `$objectToArray` ( and I think I posted a few of them ) since March this year, then it's not exactly "new news". The point I am illustrating here is whilst "possible" it's actually "impractical". Util there is a way to "sort inline" just as `$map` or `$filter` act on an array of elements "inline", then this really is not something that should be attempted using the aggregation framework.

Comment: @NeilLunn, indeed. It is even documented as available from 3.4.4 already https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/

Comment: @NeilLunn In my case, It is actually doable with the $objectToArray because I just need to do it inside a single document. Also, the structure that i followed actually saves a lot of storage space and is recommended for storing large data sets which in my case im storing a hell lot of them

Comment: Let me put it this way. If you have 20 keys, then in order to sort them you essentially `$unwind` each document into **20 new documents**. Then you sort them, then you bring them back into line per document. That's **a lot** of work simply to make keys appear in order. If you "expect them in order" then you use an "array" which has "index ordered elements" in every single language. Ordered keys may be okay in JavaScript and some other languages, but there are also plenty where it is not okay or allowed even. If you expect things in order then you are in fact doing it wrong.

Comment: I have a couple of things going with "really big" time series data keys. Some of those have been in place for 5 years or more. Not once have I had a need to sort the keys. So if you think you need to, then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the concept and are misusing it. Which leads to that you are "probably better off with an array".

Comment: @NeilLunn Looks like I need to go back and check things out more in detail. Thanks for the lesson though, atleast I know that I might need to check things again

Answer (score 0):

**Please read @NeilLunn's comments to the question first**

The "possible" yet "impractical" pipeline could be like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        data: { $objectToArray: "$data" }
    }}, 
    {$unwind: "$data"},
    {$sort: {_id:1, "data.k":-1}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", data:{$first:"$data"}}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", data:{$push:"$data"}}},
    {$project: {
        _id: 1,
        data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }            
    }}
])
```